# My app crashes immediately after start up, can't find a solution that works.

Tags: iphone, xcode, jailbreak

I have not been able to get my app to run on iOS 5.1. It crashes immediately after start up on the device. I know that app is not crashing because it runs fine on iOS 5.0. I've tried JailCoder, [this](http://iklive.org/objective-c-compiling-ios-5-software-without-developer-program/) and similar tutorials, signing manually with ldid, nothing works. Devlopement of my app has come to a halt because of this problem. Is there something else I can do? This is very frustrating.

Comment: Do you have any crash reports?

Comment: @joshOfAllTrades I don't. None are being created. I don't think that app is crashing, I think it's being killed instantly on start up.

Comment: Install syslogd from Cydia, turn it on, start app, wait for crash, see the log in /var/log/syslog. Also check whether your app executable has execute permissions.

Comment: @H2CO3 I did that and got these entries. http://pastebin.com/zjbMT0rT I see permission denied in there, so is this problem just a simple permission error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you haven't given the proper `chmod` settings to your app executable. Try (as root):

```
chmod 755 /Applications/Brandsonic\ Web\ mobile.app/Brandsonic\ Web\ mobile
```

You may also need to fake codesign the app to run:

```
ldid -S /Applications/Brandsonic\ Web\ mobile.app/Brandsonic\ Web\ mobile
```

Comment: The chmod command worked fine but the ldid did not. When I executed the command (via SSH on my Mac) I got this error:

codesign_allocate: for architecture armv6 object: /Applications/Brandsonic Web mobile.app/Brandsonic Web mobile malformed object (unknown load command 8)
util/ldid.cpp(582): _assert(78:WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0)

Comment: @Segadude if you did what I told you to do on my tutorial at iklive.org it would work, my script fakes code sign at line 12.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to respring your device after installation? I wrote the guide from iKlive Networks and I always have to respring otherwise it would just crash.